# Can i prevent the effect of the_title filter on the dashboard's posts/pages titles?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I am trying to filter the title of posts to use the result only on front pages but it also affects the dashboard one's, so any condition available to only affect the front end ones.

here is my code, which displays the title combined with the grand main category name and it works but only the matter i mentioned:

```
    function edit_title($title, $id){

        if(get_post_type($id) == 'post'){
            $allcats = get_categories();
            $catnames = array();
            foreach ($allcats as $catob){
                $catnames[$catob->name] = $catob->cat_ID;
            }
            foreach ($catnames as $catname => $catid){
                    $args = array ('fields' => 'names');
                    $catlist = wp_get_post_categories($id, $args);
                    if (in_array($catname,$catlist)){
                        $cat = get_category( $catid );
                        $catancestorsids = get_ancestors ($catid , 'category');
                        $greatgrandparent = array();
                        foreach ($catancestorsids as $catancestorid){
                            $catancestorob = get_category( $catancestorid );
                            if($catancestorob->category_parent == 0){
                                $greatgrandparent[] = $catancestorob->name;

                            }

                        }
                        $title = '<span style="background-color:#333333; padding:3px; color:#ffffff; border-radius: 4px;">'.$greatgrandparent[0].':</span> '.$title;                
                    }
            }
        }
        return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'edit_title',10,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time reading my question but fortunately i have found where the problem is and i should have wrapped the title with `!is_admin`

```
if(!is_admin()){;
    $title = '<span style="background-color:#333333; padding:3px; color:#ffffff; border-radius: 4px;">'.$greatgrandparent[0].':</span> '.$title;                
}
```

I thought to delet the question but it my be handy for any one.

Thank you.